# Problem when adding background music to video without sound

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to cut a piece of background music and loop them into a video and change the speed of the video with the command below.

```
 String[] cmd = {"-y", "-i", input, "-i", shortsound,
            "-filter_complex",
            "[0:v]trim=0:120,setpts=1/2*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v1]," +
                    "[0:v]trim=120:240,setpts=1/2*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v2];" +
                    "[1:a]atrim=0:6,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS," +
                    "asetrate=44100,aloop=-1:2e+09," +
                    "aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=1.0[bg];" +
                    "[0:a]atrim=0:120,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=2.0" +
                    ",aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[a1]," +
                    "[0:a]atrim=120:240,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=2.0," +
                    "aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[a2];" +
                    "[v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[video][audio];[audio]volume=0.5[avolume];" +
                    "[avolume][bg]amerge=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[aout]",
            "-map", "[video]", "-map", "[aout]", "-c:v", "libx264", "-c:a", "aac", "-shortest",
            "-preset", "veryfast", output, "-hide_banner"};
```

Everything was fine until I tried with a video without sound, it didn't work.
How when input is a video without sound?

Comment: i would appreciate if you accept the answer if it solved your current question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your command line won't work for any video that has audio stream because in your command you are trying to manipulate audio stream of input video in below lines :

```
 "[0:a]atrim=0:120,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=2.0" +
                ",aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[a1]," +
 "[0:a]atrim=120:240,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=2.0," +
                "aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[a2];"
```

**[0:a]** refers to audio stream of first input which is a video file, so when we have a video without audio stream, your command will end with failure

in order to solve your problem, you can check if there is any audio stream in your video file with below code:

```
private boolean isVideoContainAudioStream(String videoPath) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
    String hasAudioStream = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_AUDIO);
    if (hasAudioStream != null && hasAudioStream.equals("yes"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

so if the result of above function is equal to true, your video file contain audio stream so you can run your command else you can ignore the file or showing a warning or run an edited version of your command